# Celery stops processing

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

With roughly 0.9 million messages in rabbitmq, celery workers stopped processing tasks. On killing celery and running it again, processing resumed. Rabbit never went out of memory. Nothing suspicious in any logs or statuses except:

> ** WARNING ** Mnesia is overloaded: {dump_log,write_threshold}

from `/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit.log`. Similar symptoms were present before with around 1.6m messages en-queued.

More info:

- Celery concurrency: 4
- RAM installed: 4GB
- Swap space 8GB
- disk_free_limit (Rabbit): 8GB
- vm_memory_high_watermark: 2
- vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio: 0.75

How can the actual cause of workers stopping be diagnosed and how can it be prevented from reoccurring.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably submitting/consuming the messages from queue too fast?

If you don't need messages to be durable and can store those in memory only, it will significantly improve the RabbitMQ performance.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#using-transient-queues

Comment: Question is not about improving performance, it's about workers getting "stuck" and not processing any messages at all.